# How to get file Id of file located on Google Drive

Tags: java, google-drive-api, access-token

In my app i need to download a file which is on Google Drive, as suggested in https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-android-ui , a file id is required to download the file. Following this tutorial i am getting the file id in the intent, but i want my application to be independent. So how can i get the file id.

I tried to get the list of the file using the `children` and `files`, but both were returning 1 always. I verified number of files on my Google drive were 7.

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.